# Как отловить одинаковые значения?

Tags: массивы, php

Доброго времени суток.

Есть некий массив, который находится в переменой `$typeOfWood`:

```
array(4) { 
    [0]=> array(3) { 
        ["id"]=> string(3) "258"
        ["key"]=> string(12) "Порода"
        ["value"]=> string(6) "Дуб" }
    [1]=> array(3) { 
        ["id"]=> string(3) "271" 
        ["key"]=> string(12) "Порода" 
        ["value"]=> string(6) "Орех" }
    [2]=> array(3) { 
        ["id"]=> string(3) "273"
        ["key"]=> string(12) "Порода"
        ["value"]=> string(6) "Дуб" }
    [3]=> array(3) { 
        ["id"]=> string(3) "280" 
        ["key"]=> string(12) "Порода" 
        ["value"]=> string(6) "Орех" }
    }
```

Выводится примерно так (заранее говорю: это не ошибка, что два раза выводится одно и то же значение):

```
foreach($typeOfWood as $theType){
    echo "<p>".$theType['value']." ".$theType['value']."</p>";
```

Так вот, надо проверить, выведено ли такое же значение, и если да, то не отображать. По даному массиву надо первый раз отобразить Дуб, а второй не отображать. Первый раз отобразить Орех, а второй не отображать.

Comment: заран**е**е, http://tsya.ru

Comment: Это исправил, а посути

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$arr = array(
    array('id'=>1,  'value'=>'дуб'),
    array('id'=>2, 'value'=>'орех'),
    array('id'=>3, 'value'=>'дуб'),
    array('id'=>4, 'value'=>'орех')
);
$isset_arr = array();
foreach($arr as $v){
    if(isset($isset_arr[$v['value']])){
        continue;
    } else {
        $isset_arr[$v['value']] = 1;
    }

    echo "id = " . $v['id'] . " :: " . $v['value'] . "\n";
}
```

Код на [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/bfYcSO)